# st_transform reprojection issue with R and sf

Tags: r, sf

According to https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/reproj-geo-data.html i tried to reproject world map to Lambert with `st_transform` from `sf` package

```
library(spData)
library(sf)
library(tmap)

# test
plot(world["continent"])

# reprojection Lambert centered on Atlantic ocean

world2 <- st_transform(world["continent"],  crs = "+proj=laea +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +lon_0=-30 +lat_0=10")
```

strange mapn(yellow)

```
# plot
 plot(world2)
```

[image]

```
 # plotting with tmap (what I want but with an issue)
 tm_shape(world2) + 
 tm_fill() 

 tmap_mode("plot") 


 error : The shape world2 is invalid. See sf::st_is_valid
```

Answer (score 2):

The yellow polygon is result of your `+lon_0` and `+lat_0` parametres in `st_transfomr()`. Try to adjust them. For projection centered on lon and lat of 0 (like in the book) the crs string is:

```
"+proj=laea +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +lon_0=0 +lat_0=0"
```

So the code will be:

```
library(spData)
library(sf)
library(tmap)

plot(world["continent"])

world2 <- st_transform(world["continent"],  crs = "+proj=laea +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +lon_0=0 +lat_0=0") 
plot(world2)
```

[image]

```
tm_shape(world2) + 
 tm_fill()
```

[image]